# Changing the default MySQL user in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line, command-prompt

If I run the `mysql` or `mysqldump` programs from the command prompt, I get this in Windows:`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. I understand that 'ODBC' is the default user.  Is there a way to change this somewhere?

I switch back and forth between Windows and Linux quite frequently and the slight difference kills me.  While a simple `-u root` isn't a lot of typing, forgetting it the occasional time is quite frustrating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's hardcoded in the source code, you have to change that and rebuild it yourself. A common trick would be to create a batch/bash program with the same name as the executable (of course you have to move the executable somewhere first, even on Windows due to .bat/.exe execution order) which checks for empty arguments. If they're empty, append '-u root' to the command, otherwise bypass the arguments to the real executable

Comment: You can change the PATHEXT environment variable to override that behavior