# How can I change the default user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd

When I type `mysql` in `cmd` I get this error: *Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)*.
I'm aware of this post: [Changing the default MySQL user in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301979/changing-the-default-mysql-user-in-windows), but I don't get it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the user on the command line like:

```
mysql --user=jconstantine
```

That username is just an example. Set it to whatever user you have created in your MySQL Server instance.

You can create an options file so you don't have to type that every time. An options file is a text file. You create it with any text editor, even Notepad.

The location of this file could be one of:

- `%WINDIR%/my.ini` or %WINDIR%/my.cnf`
- `C:/my.ini` or `C:/my.cnf`

It can be others too. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

The content of the file for your purposes should be:

```
[client]
user = jconstantine
```

That username is just an example. Set it to whatever username you [created](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html) in your MySQL Server instance.

Comment: Can I also ask for the password for my new default user?

Comment: I have no idea what your password is. If you created the user, then you also defined its password. Are you asking if you can put a `password = ...` line in the options file? Yes you can.

Comment: I set the password for my user and I would normally type: `mysql -u MyUser -p`. My question was: Can I prompt the default user to enter the password by typing just `mysql` and if yes then what should I add to `my.ini` file?

Comment: Just put the line `password` in your `my.ini` and it will make the client prompt you. Just like adding the `-p` or `--password` option to the command line.